# Oracle next_day function returns wrong date

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, date-arithmetic

I am running Oracle Database 11g Express Edition. When I issue:

```
select next_day('04-JUN-15', 'Friday') from dual;
```

I am getting correct result which is '05-JUN-15'.
But when I am issuing:

```
select next_day(DATE '15-06-04', 'Friday') from dual;
```

I am getting pretty strange result which is '07-JUN-15'.
At the same time both dates looks the same for me:

```
select to_char(DATE '15-06-04', 'DD-MM-RR HH24:MI:SS'),  
       to_char(to_date('04-JUN-15'), 'DD-MM-RR HH24:MI:SS')  
       from dual;
```

Both return '04-06-15 00:00:00'.
Can someone explain why it works in this way?

Thanks!

Comment: Unbelievable that some people are still not aware of the **Y2K** problem. What is the result when you use proper date, i.e. when you use 4 digits for the year? I strongly assume this will show you the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> next_day(DATE '15-06-04', 'Friday')

You just reinvented the **Y2K** bug. Year should always be **YYYY** format in complete 4 digits. Or, use **RR** format along with **TO_DATE**. There are certain rules for the RR format you need to take care.

The **ANSI date literal** contains no time portion, and must be specified in exactly this format (**'YYYY-MM-DD'**).

Make this correction and you will get correct result:

**ANSI date literal**

```
SQL> SELECT next_day(DATE '2015-06-04', 'Friday') FROM dual;

NEXT_DAY(
---------
05-JUN-15

SQL>
```

**TO_DATE RR format**

```
SQL> SELECT next_day(TO_DATE('15-06-04', 'RR-MM-DD'), 'Friday') FROM dual;

NEXT_DAY(
---------
05-JUN-15

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

> `select next_day(DATE '15-06-04', 'Friday') from dual` => "June, 07 0015 00:00:00"

This looks like the year 15 (i.e. 2000 years ago)! Probably not what you are looking for.

`select DATE '15-06-04' from dual` => "June, 04 0015 00:00:00"

This is reading your date as YY-MM-DD with the year being 0015. I'm not sure why you are casting a string using `DATE`, `to_date` should do what you want and you are using it already.